# How to disable cross sign in mouse cursor

Tags: 20.04

If you notice, there is a cross sign at the mouse cursor. I've changed this setting last time but I forgot how to disable it.

[image]

I've checked mouse setting, but can't find anything to disable or change this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's actually `Crosshairs` under Zoom Options.

Here the full sequence

1. Settings
2. Universal Access
3. Seeing > Zoom > Crosshairs
4. Disable it

[image]